# Get file from internet requiring web login using Python

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to download a series of trading history files from www.mql5.com.  I want to automate this using Python which I have never done before.  The website requires login so I have been following the tutorial at [this](https://pybit.es/requests-session.html) page regarding the login/session.  What I am trying to achieve is the equivalent of going to this page:

https://www.mql5.com/en/auth_login

and logging in, and then going to a link such as this:

https://www.mql5.com/en/signals/552592/export/history

If I do this in Chrome, pasting that link into the browser (once logged in) downloads a csv file immediately to my Downloads folder without opening any real page in the browser.

The code that I have written is:

```
import requests

loginurl = 'https://www.mql5.com/en/auth_login'
fileurl = 'https://www.mql5.com/en/signals/552592/export/history'

loginpayload = {
    'Login': '<mylogingoeshere>',
    'Password': '<mypasswordgoeshere>'
}

session = requests.Session()

post = session.post(loginurl, data=loginpayload)

print post.status_code

myfile = session.get(fileurl)
open('<pathtowhereIwantfilestogo>\\420560.history.csv', 'wb').write(myfile.content)
```

When I run the code, the print statement prints "200", but it is hard to tell whether it's really "logged in".  I was sort of expecting that just "visiting" the file URL in python might be enough to make it appear on my computer somewhere, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  I decided to use the first example on [this](https://dzone.com/articles/simple-examples-of-downloading-files-using-python) page regarding getting the actual file.  From my mode, a csv file is created at the path specified, but it appears to contain lines of HTML code from the website rather than the file data I was expecting.  The real file when downloaded properly is a list of trading data.

Please would it be possible for someone to help me identify where I might have gone wrong?  It looks like "myfile" is getting a webpage rather than the real file that I am after. There are millions of pages about requesting files/logging in on Google but many of them seem to be much more complicated than what I am trying to achieve, or I simply don't understand them!  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since we can't authenticate to the site it will be difficult for us to spot the problem. If you examine the HTML returned by your `session.get` call, does it include any information (such as an authentication error) that may shed light on the problem?

Comment: Thank you @larsks.  myfile.text gives an error stating that "charmap" codec can't encode characters in position 6695-6701: character maps to <defined>.  myfile.content gives a lot of HTML text.  In the HTML text it suggests that is not really logged in, but its very hard to tell.  If it would be useful to post the HTML response here (of myfile or the login response) I can edit my most and add it!

Comment: Also if I print post.cookies it prints <RequestsCookieJar[]> which again suggests that its not really logging in as expected, but I can't really understand why as the principle is seemingly so simple!

Comment: It's possible that the website relies on javascript to handle the authentication, in which case `requests` will be unable to log in.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add headers and proper Payload wile making login request.

```
import requests

login_url = 'https://www.mql5.com/en/auth_login'
file_url = 'https://www.mql5.com/en/signals/552592/export/history'

login_payload = {
    "RedirectAfterLoginUrl":"https://www.mql5.com/",
    "RegistrationUrl":"",
    "ShowOpenId":"True",
    "ViewType":"0",
    "Login":"USER_ID",
    "Password":"PASSWORD"
}

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.mql5.com',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Referer': 'https://www.mql5.com/en/auth_login',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin': 'https://www.mql5.com'
}

session = requests.Session()

post = session.post(login_url, data=login_payload, headers=headers)

print post.status_code

my_file = session.get(file_url)
with open('<pathtowhereIwantfilestogo>\\420560.history.csv', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(my_file.content)
```

Comment: Thank you mkadia.  I think the login code is working better because when I print response.cookies there is a '<Cookie uniq=504324..... for .mql5.com/>' but the fileurl request is still getting the HTML page, rather than the .csv file that was intended.